# I want a vector of derived class pointers as base class pointers

Tags: c++, inheritance

In C++, the vector class stores an array of objects. In this case, I am storing pointers to derived class objects (Dogs). At some point, I want to treat this vector as pointers to objects of the base class (Animals). This is the "right"/non controversial way right? Why can't I do this?

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Animal { }; 
class Dog : public Animal { };

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    vector<Dog*> dogs;
    dogs.push_back(new Dog());
    dogs.push_back(new Dog());
    vector<Animal*> animals = dogs; // This doesn't seem to work.

    // This is really what I want to do...
    vector<Animal*> all_animals[] = {dogs, cats, birds};
}
```

The error:

```
Untitled.cpp:11:18: error: no viable conversion from 'vector<class Dog *>' to 'vector<class Animal *>'
    vector<Animal*> animals = dogs;
                    ^         ~~~~
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_vector.h:231:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'vector<Dog *>' to 'const std::vector<Animal *, std::allocator<Animal *> > &' for 1st argument
  vector(const vector& __x)
  ^
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is a copy constructor for a `std::vector` but it requires you to copy the exact same type of vector.  Fortunately, there is another constructor which takes a pair of iterators and adds all the elements in the range, so you can do this:

```
vector<Animal*> animals(dogs.begin(),dogs.end());
```

This creates a new vector of `Animal` pointers by iterating through each `Dog` pointer.  Each `Dog` pointer is converted to an `Animal` pointer as it goes.

Here is a more complete example (using C++11):

```
#include <vector>

struct Animal { };

struct Dog : Animal { };

struct Cat : Animal { };

struct Bird : Animal { };

int main(int,char**)
{
  Dog dog1, dog2;
  Cat cat1, cat2;
  Bird bird1, bird2;
  std::vector<Dog *> dogs = {&dog1,&dog2};
  std::vector<Cat *> cats = {&cat1,&cat2};
  std::vector<Bird *> birds = {&bird1,&bird2};
  std::vector<std::vector<Animal *>> all_animals = {
    {dogs.begin(),dogs.end()},
    {cats.begin(),cats.end()},
    {birds.begin(),birds.end()}
  };
}
```

Comment: @Mahesh Because you don't ever want to be able to do `void oops(vector<Animal*>& animals) { animals.push_back(new Cat); } vector<Dog*> dogs; oops(dogs);`.

Comment: There's a drawback in this solution, though: `all_animals` maintains *copies* of the other vectors' contents, so if updating one of these, `all_animals` won't be updated automatically...

Comment: @molbdnilo what kind of an argument that is? How is it different from `void oops(Animal& animal) { animal = *new Cat; } Dog* dog; oops(*dog);` ?

Answer (score 4):

You can do what you really want to do with no problems at all! That is, simply do:

```
class Animal {
   public:
      std::string GetNoise() const = 0;
};
class Dog : public Animal {
   public:
      std::string GetNoise() const { return "Bark!"; }
};
class Cat : public Animal {
   public:
      std::string GetNoise() const { return "Meow"; }
      bool        LikesSleeping() const { return true; }
};

Dog* d = new Dog;
Cat* c = new Cat;
vector<Animal*> all_animals;
all_animals.push_back(d, c);

// then, later...

// this will print "Bark!"
std::cout << all_animals[0]->GetNoise() std::endl;

// if you know the type somehow
Cat* x = dynamic_cast<Cat*>(all_animals[1]);
const bool y = x->LikesSleeping();
```

The reason that your code didn't work the way you expect is that: `std::vector<Dog*>` is a totally **different class** from `std::vector<Animal*>`.

In other words, Dog inherits from Animal, yes, but a `std::vector<X>` does not inherit from `std::vector<Y>` -- no matter how X and Y are related!

Templates don't give the vector much intelligence; they just define a new class. You can think of it this way:

```
class vectorOfDogs {
    Dog* myDogs;
    //...
}

class vectorOfAnimals {
    Animal* myAnimals;
    //...
}
```

Does `vectorOfDogs` inhert from `vectorOfAnimals`? Clearly not! But all that's been done is changing the name of the class from `std::vector<Dog*>` to `vectorOfDogs`.

Comment: There is no such function `vector.push_back(d, c);` with 2 arguments.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted solution is fine, but has one big drawback: It maintains copies of the contents of the vectors in question. Any time one of the vectors is updated, we need to update the redundant data as well to keep global state consistent. Not being very fond of, decided to try to get around this issue (unfortunately needed to discover that this requires quite some work...):

```
class AllAnimals
{
    struct Wrapper
    {
        virtual ~Wrapper() { }
        virtual Animal* begin() = 0;
        virtual Animal* end() = 0;
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct SpecificWrapper : Wrapper
    {
        T& animals;
        SpecificWrapper(T& animals)
                : animals(animals)
        { }
        Animal* begin() override
        {
            return *animals.begin();
        }
        Animal* end() override
        {
            return *animals.end();
        }
    };

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Wrapper>> wrappers;

public:
    class iterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, Animal*>
    {
        friend class AllAnimals;
        decltype(wrappers)::iterator current, end;
        Animal* animal;
        iterator(decltype(current) begin, decltype(end) end)
                : current(begin), end(end)//, animal(nullptr)
        {
            while(current != end && (*current)->begin() == (*current)->end())
            {
                ++current;
            }
            animal = current == end ? nullptr : (*current)->begin();
        }
    public:
        bool operator==(iterator const& other)
        {
            return current == other.current && animal == other.animal;
        }
        bool operator!=(iterator const& other)
        {
            return !(*this == other);
        }
        iterator& operator++()
        {
            if(++animal == (*current)->end())
            {
                ++current;
                animal = current == end ? nullptr : (*current)->begin();
            }
            return *this;
        }
        iterator operator++(int)
        {
            iterator i(*this);
            ++*this;
            return i;
        }
        Animal* operator*()
        {
            return animal;
        }
        Animal* operator->()
        {
            return animal;
        }
    };

    iterator begin()
    {
        return iterator(wrappers.begin(), wrappers.end());
    }
    iterator end()
    {
        return iterator(wrappers.end(), wrappers.end());
    }

    template <typename T>
    void push_back(std::vector<T*>& v)
    {
        wrappers.emplace_back(new SpecificWrapper<decltype(v)>(v));
    }
};
```

I only implemented a forward iterator so far, one could provide further operators to make a bidirectional or even random access one from. Additionally, we might add const iterators, (const) reverse iterators, ...

Answer (score 0):

You may Create your Dog Vector as:

```
vector<Animal*> dogs;
```

And cast your dog objects before inserting them

```
dogs.push_back((Animal*)new Dog());
```

Later, cast back while accessing