# Conversion to a vector of unique base class pointers

Tags: c++, vector, casting, unique-ptr

**EDIT**

As requested, I am providing an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Animal
{
    public:
        virtual void printName() = 0;
};

class Dog: public Animal
{
    public:
        virtual void printName() { cout << "Dog" << endl; }
};

class Cat: public Animal
{
    public:
        virtual void printName() { cout << "Cat" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    vector<vector<unique_ptr<Animal>> *> groups_of_animals;

    vector<unique_ptr<Dog>> dogs;
    vector<unique_ptr<Cat>> cats;

    dogs.push_back(unique_ptr<Dog>(new Dog));
    dogs.push_back(unique_ptr<Dog>(new Dog));
    cats.push_back(unique_ptr<Cat>(new Cat));

    groups_of_animals.push_back(reinterpret_cast<vector<unique_ptr<Animal>> *>(&dogs));
    groups_of_animals.push_back(reinterpret_cast<vector<unique_ptr<Animal>> *>(&cats));

    for(auto &group: groups_of_animals)
        for(auto &animal: *group)
            (animal) -> printName();

    return 0;
}
```

Output: *Dog Dog Cat*

Is using reinterpret cast safe and justified here? Static cast does not work.

PS I found this topic: [I want a vector of derived class pointers as base class pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223036/i-want-a-vector-of-derived-class-pointers-as-base-class-pointers) but in my situation I am using unique_ptr and want I do not want to update the *everyone* vector as soon as I update some child vector. I just want to have pointers to those child vectors.

Comment: Maybe show an example input and output, because I don't understand your question as written.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this for a simple reason that neither `reinterpret_cast`, nor `static_cast` nor `dynamic_cast` works this way.

When you have a:

```
class Superclass {};
```

and a

```
class Subclass : public Superclass {};
```

You can, under certain circumstances, use one of the appropriate casts to cast an instance of one to another.

But you cannot cast a `std::vector` of one to a `std::vector` of the other, as it seems you're attempting to do here. Neither of the two vector classes are a direct superclass or a subclass of the other vector class. `std::vector` is a template. Each instance of a template is a unique class of its own, that's not related to any other instance of the template (unless explicitly declared, as such, using specialization, etc...)

Comment: May be I do not understand something, but I am actually trying to cast a pointer to a vector of child class *pointers* to a pointer to a vector of base class *pointers*. That is, I am trying to treat vector<unique_ptr<Child>> as vector<unique_ptr<Base>>. Not vector<Child> as vector<Base>. Is this still invalid?

Comment: Yes, it's still invalid. Doesn't matter what the vector contains. The class you're casting are two different vectors. std::vector<X> and std::vector<Y> are two independent classes that are not related to each other. It doesn't matter what X or Y is, or whether X is a parent or a child of Y, or pointers to a parent or a child class. The classes in question here are two different vector classes. Full stop. Rough example: "class A  { X *ptr; }" and "class B { Y *ptr; } ". If X and Y are a parent or a child of each other, doesn't mean the same for A & B. They are two independent classes.