# Using vector<base_class*> and vector<sub_class*>

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have following classes:

```
class user
{
    ...
}; 

class System : public user
{
    private:
       vector<Driver*> drivers;
    public:
       bool find_user(string, string, vector<user*>);    
};

class Driver : public user
{
    ....
};
```

but when using

```
find_user(UN, "",drivers);
```

it has a compiler error saying irregular casting from vector to vector.
I'll be thankful if you help me.

Comment: Please tag the question with the programming language you're using!

Comment: i'm using c++ lang

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want a vector of derived class pointers as base class pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223036/i-want-a-vector-of-derived-class-pointers-as-base-class-pointers)

Comment: You can't trivially convert `vector<this>&` to `vector<that>&`. Ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the compilation error because you're trying to pass one type (`vector<Driver *>`) to anther type (`vector<user *>`) which are not convertible.

There's not enough context on what `find_user` does to answer definitely but this would get it compiling.

```
template <typename T>
bool find_user(string, string, vector<T*>) { ... };
```

Or alternatively, perhaps you meant to have the member variable declared as:

```
vector<user *> drivers;
```

Either would work, but it depends on `find_user`.