# C++. for_each errors c2672 and c3867

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, each

During working with vectors I got the problem with algorithm function "for_each". As i think, the main problem is in transporting function from the parent class to derived class. But I don't know how to deal with this errors:

```
error C3867: 'List::outF': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
error C2672: 'std::for_each': no matching overloaded function found
```

```
class RobSec : public Robots {
public:
int number;
int wifi;
void outF(int i) {
    cout << "" << i << endl;
}

class List : public RobSec, public RobF {
public:
vector<RobSec>RbSec;
vector<RobF>RbF;
vector<int>numb;
List(int k) {
    vector<RobSec>RbSec(k);
    vector<RobF>RbF(k);
}
~List() {
}

void setList(int size, RobSec *ArrSec, RobF *ArrF) {
    for (int l = 0; l < size; l++) {
        RbSec.push_back(ArrSec[l]);
        RbF.push_back(ArrF[l]);
    }
    for_each(RbSec[0].number, RbSec[size - 1].number, RobSec::outF); //Errors C2672 and C3867
}
```

And also List class is derived to several classes, but I want to read out data only from one of them.
After changing code on lambda solution or bind solution:

```
for_each(RbSec[0].number, RbSec[size-1].number,[this](auto& i) 
{ outF(i); });
```

I always got the same error:

```
error C2100: illegal indirection
```

Comment: Unrelated: It seems odd that `List` is a child of stuff that it contains. It's like saying `List` is a `Robot` than contains other `Robot`s. I like my combining robots as much as any other child who watched '80s cartoons, but this use of inheritance smells a little funny.

Comment: @user4581301 the main specific of my task is to make a class, which contains all hyerarchy of Robot classes.

Comment: Your constructor declares local variables and discards them

Comment: Contains is different from is. One can easily make a list of `Robot`s without the list being a `Robot`. I'd check your implementation with whoever gave the assignment to make sure you are on the right path.

Comment: @M.M As I understood, you are about that vectors are in constructor? I tried to remove the declaration from the List constructor but nothing has changed. The same problem
   class List : public RobSec, public RobF {
   public:
 vector<RobSec>RbSec;
 vector<RobF>RbF;
 vector<int>numb;
 List() {
 }
 ~List() {
 }

Comment: @user4581301 The task is: The List should have only one array (vector) containing all the classes of the hierarchy in the list class fields. But only one is quite difficult for me, so I made 2 vectors of base classes.

Comment: The solution to the problem M.M brings up is to use the [Member Initializer List](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) to initialize the `vector` members. The solution to the assigned problem is to use a single `vector` of pointers to `Robot`s. With pointers you can take advantage of  polymorphism and the `Robot hierarchy. Here is a good example using Animals you can use as an example: [I want a vector of derived class pointers as base class pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223036/i-want-a-vector-of-derived-class-pointers-as-base-class-pointers).

Comment: But note that `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Robot>>` is likely the correct modern way. You may have a case for `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Robot>>`  and you may not have compiler support for `vector`s of smart pointers and have to use raw pointers, `std::vector<Robot*>`, as per the example above.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you for idea. I'll try it now and will write if something will be changed