# Cast vector with base class pointers to back to subclass

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

I want to cast a vector of base class pointers to a vector of subclass pointers. As far as I understand it, object slicing does not apply here because the vector consists of pointers.

Casting a single object with `txt_specific *o = (txt_specific *) x.front();` works but I cannot figure out how to cast the whole vector at once.

```
#include <vector>

class txt_base {
  int a;
};

class txt_specific : public txt_base {
  int b;

  void do_stuff(){};
};

int main() {
  std::vector<txt_base *> x {new txt_specific()};

  // This cast does not work
  std::vector<txt_specific *> y = (std::vector<txt_specific *>) x;

  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**: I tried the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223036/i-want-a-vector-of-derived-class-pointers-as-base-class-pointers) but it does not seem to work.

**2. EDIT**: To explain a bit the situation in which that problem occurred: This code below demonstrates it. The actual parse function is called several times in different places.

```
#include <vector>

class txt_base {};
class txt_specific1 : public txt_base {};
class txt_specific2 : public txt_base {};

enum t {
  TYPE1,
  TYPE2
};

void parser1(std::vector<txt_specific1 *> vec) {}
void parser2(std::vector<txt_specific2 *> vec) {}

void parse(std::vector<txt_base *> &x, t type) {
  // the cast would be needed in this function
  switch (type){
    case TYPE1: parser1(x); break;
    case TYPE2: parser2(x); break;
  }
}

int main() {
  std::vector<txt_base *> x {new txt_specific1()};
  parse(x, TYPE1);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't cast the whole vector at once. vector<X> is not convertible to vector<Y> no matter what X and Y are. The real question is why you want to do this, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: You can't, and you don't need it.

Comment: Chances are you do not want to cast objects of user-defined classes.

Comment: _"but it does not seem to work"_ In what way? To do what? You didn't tell us what you're trying to do. Only how you think you want to do it.

Comment: The vector with base class pointers is passed to a function. This function then calls different parsers depending on the txt type (the subclasses) which is known via a different parameter

Comment: Sorry about the wrong dupe!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I added a second piece of code to better show the actual problem

Comment: I see no reason there for the proposed cast. Why do `parser1` and `parser2` need to take those types?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. Are you talking about changing the parameter of `parser1` and `parser2` so they take a `txt_base`?

Comment: I'm asking you to explain why they don't already take a `vector<txt_base*>&`, as that seems to be the crux of your problem, but you haven't fully explained it yet

Comment: But then I would need to cast them inside of the `parser1` or `parser2` functions to be able to call functions specific to `txt_specific1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to cast a vector of base class pointers to a vector of subclass pointers.

You can't.

Let me try to explain why that would be a problem if the compiler let you do that. Let's say you have another class derived from `txt_base`.

```
#include <vector>

class txt_base {
  int a;
};

class txt_specific : public txt_base {
  int b;

  void do_stuff(){};
};

class txt_utf8 : public txt_base {
  // ...
  // Member data
  // ...

  void do_stuff(){};
};

int main() {
  std::vector<txt_base *> x {new txt_specific(), new text_utf8()};

  // Let's say te compiler allowed this
  std::vector<txt_specific *> y = (std::vector<txt_specific *>) x;

  txt_specific* ptr = y[1];
  // Now you have ptr of type txt_specific that really points to a txt_utf8.
  // Dereferencing ptr and using it member variables and member functions will 
  // lead to undefined behavior.
}
```

> Casting a single object with `txt_specific *o = (txt_specific *) x.front();` works but I cannot figure out how to cast the whole vector at once.

I hope I have explained why you should not attempt to do that. The choices for you are:

1. Get a pointer to the base class and then perform a `dynamic_cast`. Please note that you'll need to change the base class to have at least one `virtual` member function before using `dynamic_cast`. Making the destructor `virtual` is the easiest choice. It is also appropriate when you want to delete derived class objects using a base class pointer.

   ```
   class txt_base {
     public:
        virtual ~txt_base() {}

     private:
        int a;
   };
   ```

   and

   ```
   txt_base* ptr = x.front();
   txt_specific* o = dynamic_cast<txt_specific *>(ptr);
   if ( o != nullptr )
   {
      // Use o
   }
   ```
2. Keep a vector of derived class pointers. Then you don't have to worry about casting.

Comment: Thanks for the longer explanation. I do understand why it can lead to undefined behaviour. The point is that I know that all elements in the vector have the same type and I thought maybe a cast is possible then

Comment: @elya5 If you really know the type in advance, I'm sure there is a way to change the code so that it's still generic and you don't have an hardcoded type such as the base class.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

A vector of one thing is not pointer-compatible with a vector of some other thing.

Comment: @MaxLanghof, while the post you marked as duplicate is strongly related to the subject, the crux of the problem is not the same. In that post the OP wants to automatically cast a vector of deviced class pointers to a vector of base class pointers. In this post, the OP wants to automatically cast a vector of base class pointers to a vector of derived class pointers. That's a very subtle but important difference.

Comment: You're right, I'll be more careful next time. Although I'm still suspicious that you verified the lack of a dupe target in 1 minute flat ;)

Comment: I was in the middle of my answer when I noticed that the question was closed. When I reopened the question, SO had saved my answer :) I didn't reopen the question just to be able to post my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For any class template:

```
template <typename T> class Foo;
```

`Foo<T>` and `Foo<U>` are, as far as the compiler is concerned, *completely separate types* that have no conversion relationship at all, *even if T and U are related*. (In this case, T and U are pointer to base and pointer to derived.)  Thus, `std::vector<txt_specific *>` and `std::vector<txt_base *>` are unrelated, and the cast you want to do is invalid.  In some languages you can do the conversion on a container of related elements, but in c++ you cannot.

If you are a template class author you can add some templated conversions into your class, but the standard library did not do this for vector.

The only way is to make a separate container and convert each element as you insert them, or merely use the original container and downcast them as you're about to use them.  If you are guaranteed to know the correct type to downcast it to, then use static_cast.  If it's polymorphic and you cannot be sure in advance, you should use dynamic_cast and verify you get a valid (non-null) pointer result.